# Cancelation Apple Auto-renewable subscription

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Maybe someone have experience and can say me how can I detect if user cancel subscription?

FYI: I don't have trial version before subscription.

For example, user install app make subscription and after 5 months decide to cancel subscription. How I can detect it? I want to know it because depending on it I will forbid access to my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your customer bought 12 months subscription and cancelled after 5 months, you MUST deliver what he/she has bought.
You can't forbid access to your app until the end of subscription.

If your customer buy monthly subscription, same is applied, but you will verify at the end of period and allow or not the access, but never before.

From this document:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html

> A subscription is paid for in full when it is purchased. Users can
>   receive a refund only by contacting Apple customer service. For
>   example, if the user accidentally buys the wrong product, customer
>   support can cancel the subscription and issue a full or partial
>   refund. Customers may cancel a subscription in the middle of a
>   subscription period, but the subscription remains paid through the end
>   of the same period.

That said...

You can store this information in your app or do a server verification checking for new data in your receipt.

There are plenty of documents and examples that you can mix them all and do your own solution.

Here is maybe a good start:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

The new iTunes provides also a field for url call back, that send you a json with all transactions updates you have in your subscriptions.